# Ubuntu 18.04 boot time is too high

Tags: boot, drivers, acpi, ipv6

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot with windows 10 on my HP Pavilion 15 laptop (i7-8750h, 8GB RAM, Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB Graphics). I have windows 10 on a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD out of which I installed Ubuntu on a 100GB partition.

Ubuntu takes ~3min to boot which is too long.
I checked the boot log using `dmesg` on the terminal but am not able to find a particular solution. Some parts of the log are below-

```
[   28.304674] ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
[   28.304680] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
[   28.304681] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   28.304682]   Arg0:   00000000d4827883 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   28.304685]   Arg1:   00000000d8e2e5c3 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
[   28.304691] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304698] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304737] ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
[   28.304741] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
[   28.304742] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   28.304743]   Arg0:   000000006a1236a5 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   28.304745]   Arg1:   0000000058614773 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
[   28.304750] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304755] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304792] ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
[   28.304796] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
[   28.304797] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   28.304797]   Arg0:   000000006a1236a5 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   28.304799]   Arg1:   0000000010b0d4d2 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
[   28.304805] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304809] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304840] input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input11
[   28.304935] ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
[   28.304939] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
[   28.304940] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   28.304940]   Arg0:   000000006a1236a5 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000002
[   28.304942]   Arg1:   0000000058614773 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
[   28.304948] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304953] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.304989] ACPI Error: Field [D128] at bit offset/length 128/1024 exceeds size of target Buffer (160 bits) (20170831/dsopcode-235)
[   28.304992] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [HWMC]
[   28.304993] Initialized Arguments for Method [HWMC]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[   28.304994]   Arg0:   000000006a1236a5 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000003
[   28.304996]   Arg1:   0000000010b0d4d2 <Obj>           Buffer(20) 53 45 43 55 01 00 00 00
[   28.305001] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \HWMC, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[   28.305006] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.WMID.WMAA, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
```

```
[   57.223498] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   57.223499] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   57.223500] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   72.479544] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   73.118840] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eno1: link down
[   73.118970] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready
[   73.219866] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   73.843272] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   74.922172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[  105.606945] wlo1: authenticate with e4:46:da:97:22:1d
[  105.607275] wlo1: send auth to e4:46:da:97:22:1d (try 1/3)
[  105.609899] wlo1: authenticated
[  105.616013] wlo1: associate with e4:46:da:97:22:1d (try 1/3)
[  105.628806] wlo1: RX AssocResp from e4:46:da:97:22:1d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=7)
[  105.629150] wlo1: associated
[  105.862745] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  145.733942] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
[  175.120308] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  175.120315] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  175.120318] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  187.978585] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

But even besides these there are multiple places where events take 5-10s and there are a lot of them.
I am unable to find a particular thing that is causing the huge lag.

Please help me with this.

**EDIT 1:**
`systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` results in -

```
1min 44.210s apt-daily.service
    1min 18.450s postgresql@10-main.service
    1min 15.205s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         58.390s fstrim.service
         31.935s dev-sdb6.device
         28.224s snapd.service
         21.987s networkd-dispatcher.service
         20.731s phpsessionclean.service
         18.816s dev-loop23.device
         18.615s dev-loop22.device
         18.480s gpu-manager.service
         18.368s dev-loop24.device
         18.307s dev-loop25.device
         18.137s grub-common.service
         18.110s dev-loop20.device
         17.286s dev-loop15.device
         17.158s dev-loop21.device
         16.665s dev-loop19.device
         16.648s dev-loop17.device
         15.046s dev-loop11.device
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` results in-

```
graphical.target @2min 17.958s
└─multi-user.target @2min 17.957s
  └─postgresql.service @2min 2.541s +143ms
    └─postgresql@10-main.service @44.090s +1min 18.450s
      └─basic.target @44.051s
        └─sockets.target @44.051s
          └─snapd.socket @43.990s +60ms
            └─sysinit.target @43.876s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @40.817s +3.059s
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @38.798s +1.520s
                  └─local-fs.target @38.796s
                    └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @2min 48.252s
                      └─run-user-1000.mount @2min 30.698s
                        └─swap.target @35.602s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c8bb376c\x2dd620\x2d4b47\x2da8fb\x2d652c38543811.swap @33.503s +2.098s
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c8bb376c\x2dd620\x2d4b47\x2da8fb\x2d652c38543811.device @33.502s
```

**EDIT 2:**
After removing `postgresql` the boot time is still about 2min

`systemd-analyze blame | head -20` gives:

```
         41.367s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         20.468s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
         20.409s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-82.mount
         19.986s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-81.mount
         19.908s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-40.mount
         19.042s snap-core-6818.mount
         18.939s snap-heroku-3762.mount
         18.775s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
         18.184s dev-sdb6.device
         14.139s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
         14.128s snap-vlc-770.mount
         14.032s snap-heroku-3685.mount
         13.816s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-258.mount
         13.740s snap-core18-941.mount
         13.631s snap-core-4917.mount
         13.577s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
         13.523s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
         13.433s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-319.mount
         13.411s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
         13.094s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-180.mount
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain` gives-

```
graphical.target @1min 23.456s
└─multi-user.target @1min 23.454s
  └─kerneloops.service @51.067s +8ms
    └─network-online.target @51.065s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @42.081s +8.983s
        └─NetworkManager.service @38.105s +3.972s
          └─dbus.service @31.790s
            └─basic.target @31.759s
              └─sockets.target @31.759s
                └─snapd.socket @31.657s +101ms
                  └─sysinit.target @31.633s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @30.948s +685ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @30.094s +848ms
                        └─local-fs.target @30.093s
                          └─run-user-121.mount @50.162s
                            └─swap.target @22.765s
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c8bb376c\x2dd620\x2d4b47\x2da8fb\x2d652c38543811.swap @22.563s +201ms
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c8bb376c\x2dd620\x2d4b47\x2da8fb\x2d652c38543811.device @22.563s
```

Also just in case it might help - for most of the time the screen is blank and the ubuntu logo appears for a short period (10-20s I assume) after which the login screen appears.

**EDIT 3-**
Also `systemd-analyze` reveals -

```
Startup finished in 3.976s (firmware) + 49.943s (loader) + 6.720s (kernel) + 1min 20.403s (userspace) = 2min 21.043s
graphical.target reached after 1min 17.190s in userspace
```

Loader is taking 49.94s

**EDIT 4-**
After reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04, the boot log show a new error-

```
[   47.471182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   65.656882] show_signal_msg: 28 callbacks suppressed
[   65.656884] gnome-shell[1072]: segfault at 20 ip 00007fc16a2fa81d sp 00007ffdf619a4e0 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7fc16a20c000+156000]
[   67.640490] gnome-shell[1177]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f8a8430781d sp 00007fff201dba60 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f8a84219000+156000]
[  101.336776] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  101.336784] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  101.336788] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  103.556549] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

**After Installing Ubuntu 19.04**
The Graphics driver problem was solved, and I got the latest Nvidia drivers automatically installed with Ubuntu 19.04. Still the boot time didn't improve.

The SMART Data & Self-Tests screen shows the following-
[image: SMART Data & Self-Tests Screen]

`grep -i sda /var/log/syslog* | more` gives-
[image: SDA]
[image: SDA]
[image: SDA]

`grep -i ata /var/log/syslog* | more` gives-
[image: ATA]
[image: ATA]
[image: ATA]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the outputs of `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` please?

Comment: @ByteCommander I have added the outputs above

Comment: Looks like the main culprit is the postgresql service here. Do you need that to be running at boot?

Comment: Yes I just realised that @Byte Commander. I don't actually need it. How much time does it take? I mean the `blame` output above is showing it to be taking ~1min I think.

Comment: The ACPI errors indicate a problem with your system BIOS. Check to see if HP has published a BIOS update for your computer, and apply it when it becomes available.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I updated the BIOS to the latest version but the errors still persist

Comment: +1 for thorough investigation.

Answer (score 1):

So the `systemd-analyze` outputs suggest that `postgresql@10-main.service` is the main culprit that slows down the boot time.

If you don't need a PostgreSQL server running on your system and starting automatically during boot, you can either uninstall it completely with

```
sudo apt remove postgresql*
```

or you should be able to keep it installed and just disable automatic starting of the service at boot with

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql
```

You can then still manually start the service for the current session with

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

Comment: Even after removing postgresql, the boot time still is ~2min. I think there are multiple stuff that are slowing down the boot.

Comment: Can you update the two `systemd-analyze` outputs with what they show now that postgresql is gone?

Comment: I have added the new outputs in my edits

Answer (score 1):

1. **check that you have the latest BIOS**

   - `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` # get the current BIOS version
   - go to https://support.hp.com, enter your serial #, go to download area, check for newer BIOS
   - download and install newer BIOS
2. **slow boot**

   - you have in excess of two dozen snap applications installed
   - `snap list` # to see them all
   - `sudo snap remove xxxx` # to remove the snap application
   - `sudo apt-get install xxxx` # to reinstall application as a regular application
3. **check your file system**

   - boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
   - open a `terminal` window
   - type `sudo fdisk -l`
   - identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
   - type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
   - repeat the fsck command if there were errors
   - type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Since this didn't fix the problem...

<strike>Since the BIOS update didn't take care of the ACPI errors, and HP doesn't seem to want to fix their BIOS, we'll do this...</strike>

`sudo pico /etc/modprobe.d/acpi_fix.conf` # create a new file

Enter the following text into the empty file...

```
blacklist acpi_power_meter
```

Then save the file...

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd>

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Then...

`reboot` # reboot the computer

**Update #2:**

fstrim was running on sdb6 causing a boot slowdown.

one disk has SMART data that indicates high read/seek/ECC error rates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93349/discussion-between-aneesh-sharma-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 0):

Disable the plymouth in grub to get faster boot (plymouth-quit-wait-service) with

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

After saving the change you must update the grub with

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then restart the machine.